# How to save model weights in order to use later?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a model using Mask RCNN; it saves the model after every epoch as `mask_rcnn_building_cfg_0001.h5` (number corresponds epoch number).
I use pre-trained weights for Transfer Learning, which works fine. But now I want to use my own trained model to further train as it is much more optimized.
In codebase, there is this part:

```
        callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=self.log_dir,
                                    histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False),
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(self.checkpoint_path,
                                        verbose=0, save_weights_only=True),
    ]
```

So normally I have to be able to call `model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_building_cfg_0001.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])`

and use saved model for resuming training, but training does not start.  But the same `load_weights()` function works with the pretrained model downloaded from internet and model continues training.

Now, how should I set model paremeters in order to save weights after each  epoch, for using in further trainings as pretrained weights?
My best guess is I somehow have to exclue output layer from `mask_rcnn_building_cfg_0001.h5`, but not sure hw to do that.

Comment: Please also show the error message you got when you tried to load your own saved weights

Comment: There is not error message, it creates "events.out.tfevents.1624269673.RXITM187" and finishes with exit code 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

# Loads the weights
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

Complete guidelines on save and load model is given in Tensorflow doc. Please find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training).